# How to create memory on TPM

Tags: memory, tpm

I have generated key using GPG and want to store this key in TPM. I tried to store this key using "tpm2_nvwrite" .

I used command `tpm2_nvwrite -x 0X1500011 -a 0X40000001 -P 'mypassword' -f temp.data` but getting error as `Failed to initialize tcti context: 0x1`.

Can somebody suggest how to see available memory indices in my TPM ? 
Also should i use the present indices or can i create a new memory index?

Comment: Have you allocated enough memory on handle 0x1500011 with nvdefinespace?

Comment: No, i have not allocated any memory and never used nvdefinespace. And i dont see any tool by name "tpm2_nvdefinespace". Instead i see "tpm2_nvdefine". I treid command `tpm2_nvdefine 0X1500011` but getting error as `failed to initialize tcti context: 0X1`

Comment: I get this error if i try to execute the tpm2_XXX commands on devices without a tpm (missing /dev/tpmX).

Comment: I have a tpm, where am able to perfrom "tpm_sealdata" and other operations. Only with nvram am facing issue

Comment: I guess you have a tpm 1.2 since you work with the tpm-tools (including tpm_sealdata). A tpm 2 is required to use tpm2-tools (including tpm2_nvwrite). You can check your tpm version with "dmesg | grep -i tpm".

Comment: I know that i have both TPm1.2 and TPM2.0 on my machine. Earlier i was working with TPM1.2 so used "tpm_sealdata". Now i switched to TPM2.0 and i dont see any sealdata option here(but i see "tpm2_unsealdata"). So i thought of creating memory first then looking for sealing.

Comment: We need more information here. Which version of tpm2-tools are you using? The problem is that the tools cannot connect to your TPM. Is there a `/dev/tpm0` (or `/dev/tpmrm0`)? Do you have r/w permissions? Did you try passing `tpm2_xxx --tcti=device:/dev/tpm0`? Try also to enable logging: `TSS2_LOG=all+TRACE tpm2_xxx`. Please update your question to give us more details.

The command `tpm2_getcap properties-fixed` should always work if you did properly startup the TPM using `tpm_startup -c`.